# How to create a collection for the TabControl.ItemsSource from the class library that is created and used in the application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, custom-controls, itemssource

I have a library of custom classes with the classes `MyTabItem, MyTabControl, MyGrid`. When you drag `MyTabItem` (has a value of ViewModel) on the `MyGrid`, the `MyGrid_Drop` event is triggered. At this point, `MyTabControl` is created and I need to create a collection (`ObservableCollection <ViewModelBase> Pages`) in the application namespace and specify it in the `MyTabControl.ItemsSource`. After add `MyTabItem` to this collection.

Code in the application:

```
public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> Pages { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();
```

Code in the library:

```
private void MyGrid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetData(typeof(MyTabItem)) is MyTabItem tabItemSource)
            {
                if (InstanceTabControl.ItemsSource == null)
                {
                    // Here I need to create a collection of ViewModels with the type as the TabItemSource.Content.
                }

                if (InstanceTabControl.ItemsSource is IList list)
                {
                    var source = tabItemSource.Content;

                    list.Remove(source);
                    list.Add(source);

                    InstanceTabControl.SelectedIndex = list.Count - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    InstanceTabControl.Items.Remove(tabItemSource);
                    InstanceTabControl.Items.Add(tabItemSource);

                    InstanceTabControl.SelectedIndex = InstanceTabControl.Items.Count - 1;
                }

            }
        }
```

By [reference](https://github.com/YuryYatskov/PeopleDemo) sample project PeopleDemo.

1. I can use the `Func <T, TResult>` delegate to create a collection in the application, but can I do without it?
2. Now the `Pages` collection is in `ShellViewModel`. It seems that I will need this collection into a collection of subcollections of view models and then for each created `MyTabControl` in the library to create my own subcollection. But how then to bind such a subcollection in xaml (`<adc:MyTabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}">`)?

Please direct me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Inside the library, I use the `ObservableCollection<object> Pages` collection. Each instance of MyTabControl has its own collection.
I can pass a type through a generic to the class that controls the creation of collections.